# Where is Imo Messenger media gallery files are saved on hard disk in desktop version (Windows)?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, path

I'm using desktop version of Imo Messenger (version 0.9.9) on MS-windows 10.

Where is Media Gallery (and of course chat history) files are stored on my Hard drive?

Imo was installed in this path, automatically: "C:\Users\PARMER\AppData\Roaming\Imo Messenger\"

I want access photos that sent or received on "Imo Messenger" application with windows file explorer.

Thanks.

(I need "imo-messenger" tag, but I haven't enough reputation.)

Comment: Welcome to **Android** StackExchange.